# Cordova and build process

Tags: android, xml, cordova, ant

I am developing an application with Cordova Phonegap 3.5 which will be shared with several developers.

I have implemented this [plugin](https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/blob/master/v3/README.md) within my Phonegap 3.5 application. My concern is the following:

```
Create res/values/billing_key.xml, and add your public key as follows:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <resources>
  <string name="billing_key">MIIBIjANBgk...AQAB</string>
</resources>
```

As far as I understand, each developer will need to create manually this file in the generated project located here:

```
platforms/android/res/values
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to create this file automatically in 'platforms\android\res\values' when running 'cordova build android' ?
2. A way to do it would be to create an ant script that will run 'cordova build android' + generate this file, is there a better solution ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your plugin.xml add the following XML lines:

```
<source-file src="src/android/florentplugin.xml" target-dir="res/values" />
<config-file target="res/values/florentplugin.xml" parent="/*">
   <string name="billing_key">MIIBIjANBgk...AQAB</string>
</config-file>
```

Change filenames to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Plugin hooks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/templates/hooks-README.md#plugin-hooks-pluginxml)  for this. 
Check out  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418203/add-parameters-to-cordova-cli-hook-scripts) for example.